# Prove $24\mid5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1$ using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Prove $24\mid5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1$ using induction

What I thought:

Inductive hipothesis:
$$
5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1=24k
$$

Inductive step:
$$
5^{2(n+1)}+12(n+1)^2-36(n+1)-1=24q
$$
$k,q \in \mathbb{Z}$
Then I tried doing all sorts of factoring but couldn't get quite there, what strategies should I use in these sort of problems?

E: $5^{2(n+1)}\neq5^{2n+1}...$

Comment: @CliveNewstead ugh, it was 24 divides all that. I'm tired, sorry.

Comment: $5^{2(n+1)}=5^{2n+2}$, not $5^{2n+1}$.

Comment: I'd write *induction* is bold before people start posting answers using modular arithmetic. Even then I would expect some of these to slip through.

Comment: Note that $24$ divides both $5^{2n}-1$ and $12n^2-36n$, for all $n\in \mathbb N$, which should make it more manageable.

Comment: @Git If the OP knows modular arithmetic then there is nothing wrong with using it in an inductive proof. In fact doing so greatly simplifies inductions of this sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$5^{2(n+1)}+12(n+1)^2-36(n+1)-1=$$$$=\underbrace{(24\cdot 5^{2n}+24n+12-36)}_{\text{trivially divisible by }24}+\underbrace{(5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1)}_{\text{inductive hypothesis}}$$

---

Alternatively, $$5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1=(25^n-1^n)+12(n^2-3n)$$

Here $25^n-1^n=(25-1)(25^{n-1}+25^{n-2}+\cdots+25+1)$ and $n^2-3n$ is even.

Comment: Oh god, I'm dumb. I wrote $5^{2n+1}$ instead of $5^{2(n+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$5^{2\cdot1}+12\cdot1^2-36\cdot1-1=0$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1=24k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$5^{2(n+1)}+12(n+1)^2-36(n+1)-1=$

$25\cdot5^{2n}+12n^2-12n-25=$

$25\cdot(\color{red}{5^{2n}+12n^2-36n-1})+888n-288n^2=$

$25\cdot\color{red}{24k}+888n-288n^2=$

$25\cdot24k+24\cdot(37n-12n^2)=$

$24\cdot(25k+37n-12n^2)$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ It is $\, (25^n\!-\!1) + 12n(n\!-\!1)-24n\,$ so it suffices to show $\,24\mid 25^n\!-\!1,\,\ 2\mid n(n\!-\!1),\,$ both of which are well-known (or easily proved by induction, and more conceptually so).

Answer (score 0):

One can easily verify that this function $f(n)$ satisfies the following recursion:
$$f(n) = 28f(n-1)-78f(n-2)+76f(n-3)-25f(n-4)$$

Therefore by induction it is enough to check it for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$.